# How do I do the following using only regex?

Tags: c#, regex

Say I have the following string

```
[id={somecomplexuniquestring}test1],
[id={somecomplexuniquestring}test2],[id={somecomplexuniquestring}test3],
[id={somecomplexuniquestring}test4],[id={somecomplexuniquestring}test5],
[id={somecomplexuniquestring}test6],[id={somecomplexuniquestring}test7],
[id={somecomplexuniquestring}test8],[id={somecomplexuniquestring}test9]
```

is there a way just using regex to get the following result `[id={somecomplexuniquestring}test6]`

`{somecomplexuniquestring}` are unknown strings which cannot be used in the regex.

For example, the following will not work `@"[id=[\s\S]+?test6]"` as it starts from the very first id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work??

```
\[id={.*?}test6\]
```

Comment: Thanks, I've used `\[id=.*?test6\]` as the curly braces were just a placeholder.

Answer (score 3):

Is using RegEx the best solution?  You have tagged C#, so would

```
variableWithString.Split(",").Any(x => x.Contains("test6"));
```

give you the exists match, or

```
result = variableWithString.Split(",").Where(x => x.Contains("test6"));
```

give you the match value you are seeking?

Comment: I answered this question using Regex, but I have to agree, your answer seems more elegant to me!! +1

Comment: No regex is not the best solution but it was something that bugged for a while which I didn't know how to do. I've accepted John's answer as it answers my question and is also achievable in VBA should the need arise. I will use this on .NET though.

Answer (score 1):

This all depends on exactly what the limitations of somecomplexuniquestring are. For example, if you have a guarantee that they do not contain any [ or ] characters, you can use this simple one:

```
"\[[^\[\]]*test6\]"
```

Similarly, if it could contain square brackets but no curly braces, you can do something similar:

```
"\[id={[^{}]*}test6\]"
```

HOWEVER, if you have no such guarantee, and there's some sort of escaping system for including {} or [] in that string, then you need to let us know how that works to properly answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
@"\[[^]]*]"
```

If you want a specific test number you can do this:

```
@"\[id={[^}]*}test6]"
```